# Regex grouping in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am new to Regex and I would like to replace all occurrences of `\\.\CNCBx` with `\\.\CNCBx+8` where `x` in an integer.

E.g.

```
serialPort = \\.\CNCB2
serialPort = \\.\CNCB50
```

Will change to:

```
serialPort = \\.\CNCB10
serialPort = \\.\CNCB58
```

I was trying several patterns but can't get it to work:

Find: `CNCB(\d*)`

Replace with: `($LAST_SUBMATCH_RESULT) + 8`
Doesnt work.

If its not possible I will just use python to do it, but I just wonder if it is possible in Notepad++.

Comment: Don't know if `Notepad++` has any special magic for this case, but regex and math don't usually get along well.

Comment: You can't do arithmetic in regex afaik.

Comment: I see, thanks, I will code a simple find-if-match-replace to do it.

Comment: Would that be `\\.\CNCB11`?

Comment: `\\.\CNCB11` will be `\\.\CNCB19`

Comment: @Asad, yes, you right, fixed it, thanks.

Comment: What you usually do is use a regex to find the matches and do the replacement through a callback (pretty much any programming language supports that). [Here is an example of how to do this with Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12829966/1633117). But if you want to do it with Python anyway that might go even quicker.